# JIRA JQL - Number of tickets that got resolved in a particular week

Tags: jql

I'm trying to pull a monthly report divided by weeks to see how many tickets moved from "Open" to "Resolved" per week. The tickets could have be created even before the month started.

I'm using the JIRA reports so I can pull it divided by weeks.But since I'm pulling the query at the end of the month, the problem is that the issue that was resolved in the 3rd week for example show up would just show under the numbers of the 1st week(since its only checking if the status is closed or resolved right now) which isn't what I want. Is there any "change of status on a particular time range" filter that i can use or maybe a query condition

This is my starting query:

```
issuetype in (Bug) AND status in (Closed, Resolved) AND created >= 2021-03-01 ORDER BY resolved DESC, created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **status CHANGED FROM "Open" to "Resolved"** to monitor the change of status

And **DURING (Date1, Date2)** to get the week that you want:

The new query would look something like this:

```
issuetype IN (Bug) AND status CHANGED FROM "Open" TO "Resolved" DURING (2021-03-01, 2021-03-02) ORDER BY resolved DESC, created DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, Lucas! My situation required an adjustment to this, but I got it from your answer: 
    AND status CHANGED FROM "In Progress" DURING (-1w, -0w)